# Appending an array into a object with forEach()

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

Im trying to add the array of objects(transactions) into the the array(bills) using forEach to loop and array[key].transactions to add the objects.
I have also tried to use push but that didn't work neither.

Some help would be lovely.

```
var bills = [{
    "_id": "5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001",
    "billName": "Insurance",
    "startDate": "2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 2400,
    "type": 4,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "549bf0597886c3763e000001",
    "billName": "Leasing",
    "startDate": "2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 16500,
    "type": 4,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z",
    "__v": 0
}];

var transactions = [{
    "_id": "549ea8c957b654ef64000003",
    "billId": "5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001",
    "paymentDate": "2014-12-27T12:40:41.311Z",
    "amount": 2400,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-27T12:40:41.311Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "549ea8e632ed3f6265000001",
    "billId": "549bf0597886c3763e000001",
    "paymentDate": "2014-12-27T12:41:10.582Z",
    "amount": 16500,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-27T12:41:10.582Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "549ea93452ebbd8366000001",
    "billId": "549bf0597886c3763e000001",
    "paymentDate": "2014-12-27T12:42:28.744Z",
    "amount": 16500,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-27T12:42:28.745Z",
    "__v": 0
}];
```

and

```
 var test = [];
 bills.forEach(function (bill, key) {
     test.push(bill);
     transactions.forEach(function (transaction) {
         if (transaction.billId == bill._id) test[key].transactions = transaction;
     });
 });

 console.log(test);
```

The end result should be the test object would carry the bills plus the transaction inside each bill objects as an object array.

## EDIT

The problem is that this code works in JSfiddle but doesn't work when I apply to the array comming from the mongoose find().
Here is the complete code:

```
    app.get('/getbills', function(req,res) {

    //get all bills
    allBills =  Bills.find().exec();

    //get all transactions
    allTransactions = Transactions.find().exec();

    //aggregate bills and transactions in a promise
    promise.all([allBills, allTransactions]).then(function(results){

        var bills = results[0];
        var transactions = results[1];
        var test = [];
       // var test.transactions = [];

        bills.forEach(function(bill, key) {
            bill.transactions = transactions.filter(function (transaction) {
               return transaction.billId === bill._id;
        });
            console.log(bill.transactions);
            test.push(bill);
        });

        console.log(transactions);
        res.send(test);
    });  


});
```

This, returns this:

```
[{"_id":"5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001","billName":"Jeep Insurance","startDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00.000Z","amount":2400,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-23T18:05:02.987Z","__v":0},{"_id":"549bf0597886c3763e000001","billName":"Leasing","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z","amount":16500,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z","__v":0},{"_id":"54a014bfac01ca3526000001","billName":"Test","startDate":"2014-10-28T00:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2017-12-19T23:00:00.000Z","amount":1000,"type":4,"timestamp":"2014-12-28T14:33:35.233Z","__v":0}]
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
bills.forEach(function(bill, key) {
  bill.transactions = transactions.filter(function (el) {
    return el.billId === bill._id;
  });
});

console.log(bills);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bocasi/5/edit?js,console

*jQuery version*

```
$.each(bills, function(i, bill) {
  bill.transactions = $.grep(transactions, function (el) {
    return el.billId === bill._id;
  });
});

console.log(bills);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bocasi/4/edit?js,console

**Update:**

```
app.get('/getbills', function(req, res) {

    var allBills        = Bills.find().lean().exec();
    var allTransactions = Transactions.find().lean().exec();

    promise.all([allBills, allTransactions]).then(function(results) {

        var bills        = results[0];
        var transactions = results[1];
        var test         = [];

        bills.forEach(function(bill, key) {
            bill.transactions = transactions.filter(function(transaction) {
                return transaction.billId === bill._id;
            });
        });

        res.send(bills);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Deisy Laymi lean() converts MongooseDocument to plain JavaScript Object... http://goo.gl/kxicLp

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify the bill objects directly. (You're doing that anyway)

```
bills.forEach(function (bill) {
    bill.transactions = transactions.filter(function (transaction) {
        return transaction.billId === bill._id;
    });
});
```

With your edit (and without being able to test it), I *think* it should look like this:

```
app.get('/getbills', function (req, res) {
    var allBills = Bills.find().exec();
    var allTransactions = Transactions.find().exec();

    promise.all([allBills, allTransactions]).then(function (results) {
        var bills = results[0];
        var transactions = results[1];

        bills.forEach(function (bill) {
            bill.transactions = transactions.filter(function (transaction) {
                return transaction.billId === bill._id;
            });
        });
        res.send(bills);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Tomalak. I tried the version you have shown, which works in jsfiddle but, somehow it doesn't in my local. The test array never carry the transactions array for some reason. Any idea? - The results comes form two collections in mongodb.

Comment: My local code is inside a promise.all() maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Give my modified answer a shot, please.

Comment: Still getting the same result. I have tried it before... Thanks anyway @Tomalak.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. Without any further information all I can do is guess. The code in my answer should work correctly, for all I can see.

Comment: Thank you for your help @tomalak, it turned out that the find() was missing a method (which I'm not yet sure about what it does exactly) called lean(). It's on my todo list to check that one out. Anyway, I really appreciate that you took the time to help me out!

Comment: You're welcome. I suspected the reason must be outside of the code in the examples here. I'm afraid I don't know enough about Mongoose to explain `lean()`, all I can say is that my code expects plain JavaScript objects and according to the docs `lean()` switches seems to be a switch that affects that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$.each(bills, function(index, bill){ 
    var arr_temp = []; 
    $.each(transactions, function(index, transaction){
        if(bill._id == transaction.billId){
            arr_temp.push(transaction); 
        }
    }); 
    bill.transactions = arr_temp; 
}); 

 console.log(bills);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8c7a89s2/1/

Comment: One thing i want to convey is that "forEach" does not supported by IE. using $.each of jquery should be the choice:)

Comment: @PrashantKumar IE9 in standards mode is the earliest IE to support `forEach`. If you *must* support IE8 you can simply use a polyfill.

Comment: correct but i would prefer jquery if it is allowed to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Im not sure it's a browser thing as I cannot get it to work on my localhost in FF or Chrome. See EDIT.

Comment: Why do you think that it won't work? You're logging the transactions, aren't you supposed to log the bills?